# How share users between services in docker-compose?

Tags: docker

How share users between services in docker-compose? I can create volume and mount it in /etc/ container directory, but it will hide another files/directories. Is exist any smarter idea to achieve goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `volumes` + `bind mount` to mount one container's `passwd` & `group` to another container.

Next is an example:

1. If not use volume, just verify original no `mysql` user in test service:

   **docker_compose.yaml:**

   ```
   version: "3"

   services:
     db:
       image: mysql
       command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
       restart: always
       environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
   test:
     image: ubuntu:16.04
     command: id mysql
     depends_on:
       - db
   ```

   Execute as next:

   ```
   $ docker-compose up
   Creating network "23_default" with the default driver
   Creating 23_db_1 ... done
   Creating 23_test_1 ... done
   Attaching to 23_db_1, 23_test_1
   test_1  | id: 'mysql': no such user
   db_1    | Initializing database
   23_test_1 exited with code 1
   ```

   From above, you could see the container from `ubuntu:16.04` not have the user `mysql` which is a default user in `mysql`:

   > test_1  | id: 'mysql': no such user
2. Use volumes to make `user mysql` visible to `test` container:

   **docker_compose.yaml:**

   ```
   version: "3"

   services:
     db:
       image: mysql
       command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
       restart: always
       environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
       volumes:
         - my_etc:/etc
     test:
       image: ubuntu:16.04
       command: id mysql
       depends_on:
         - db
       volumes:
         - /tmp/etc-data/passwd:/etc/passwd
         - /tmp/etc-data/group:/etc/group

   volumes:
     my_etc:
       driver: local
       driver_opts:
         type: 'none'
         o: 'bind'
         device: '/tmp/etc-data'
   ```

   Execute as next, **NOTE: we need to new `/tmp/etc-data` before up:**

   ```
   $ mkdir -p /tmp/etc-data
   $ docker-compose up
   Creating network "23_default" with the default driver
   Creating 23_db_1 ... done
   Creating 23_test_1 ... done
   Attaching to 23_db_1, 23_test_1
   db_1    | Initializing database
   test_1  | uid=999(mysql) gid=999(mysql) groups=999(mysql)
   23_test_1 exited with code 0
   ```

   From above, you can see `test` service already could have the user `mysql`：

   > test_1  | uid=999(mysql) gid=999(mysql) groups=999(mysql)

**A little explanation:**

Above solution first use `named volume` to pop the `/etc` folder of `first container` to the folder `/tmp/etc-data` on docker host machine, then the second container will use `bind mount` to separately mount `passwd` & `group` to the second container. As you see, the second container just mount the 2 files (`passwd`, `group`), so it won't hide any other files.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount only file in a docker container.

```
volumes:
    - /etc/mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql.cnf
```